# Process assistantd keep writing login keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

This is a Sierra box, the system memory was suddenly out of usage. I have checked the system to find out that the keychain process was busy and used nearly all the memory.
I had to reboot the system, then i opened keychain to see the login items list is flashing, one unknown item in login keychain was keeping being deleted and inserted. 
Want to know why, I opened activity monitor, then got to know **assistantd** was busy doing that. I killed the process, the keychain came to be in peace.
I think the process is used by Siri, as **assistantd** process came out again after I clicked the siri icon.

Even I do not use siri, I want to know why this could happen, and what is the real solution.

Comment: Are the processes you killed running as your log in user or as root / another system users? If user process, consider making a new user and letting the assistants to complete all the way and remeasure.

Comment: The process was running as login user. I have created another user, the keychain is fine with siri.  But then login back, the problem remains the same. I had to disable siri.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I have searched in **~/Library** for all the directories and files within  has **siri or assistant** in their names, and removed them all.
Then reboot, all are fine then!

Comment: That's a pretty broad stroke, but it got me looking at removing  `./Assistant/com.apple.siri.applications.laststate.plist`... I'll see if it helps and update again.